# How can I send sms with contacts?

Tags: android

I am new to android . In my application I want to send sms with contacts. How can i send sms to other through my appplication

Comment: Here is an example: http://tinyurl.com/5rluxet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
private String SENT = "SENT";
private String DELIVERED = "DELIVERED";
...
PendingIntent sentPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this.context, this.getUniqueId(), new Intent(this.SENT), 0);
PendingIntent deliveredPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this.context, this.getUniqueId(), new Intent(this.DELIVERED), 0);

String smsNumber = "+123456";

SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
sms.sendTextMessage(smsNumber, null, "sms content", this.sentPI, this.deliveredPI);
```